# subset rows with unique combination in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, dplyr, tidyr

```
> df1 = data.frame(v1=c('a','a','c','x','y','z'),v2=c('b','c','a','y','z','y'),v3=c('c','b','b','z','x','x'))
   v1 v2 v3
1  a  b  c
2  a  c  b
3  c  a  b
4  x  y  z
5  y  z  x
6  z  y  x
```

Desired o/p:

```
   v1 v2 v3
   a  b  c 
   x  y  z
```

or  (order doesn't matter)

```
   v1 v2 v3
   c  a  b
   z  y  x
```

I am trying to find a unique combination of rows in a data frame.

I have tried

```
unique(df[,c('v1','v2','v3'))
```

But, I am not getting desired output. I have dataframe with multiple combinations and which also include NA.
Please help me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why that is your expected output? There are three unique rows. Do you just want all unique values in the dataframe?

Comment: try `unique(df1[1,])`

Comment: I want complete unique combination. Here in my case I can see only three alphabet occurring in different columns. I want to subset such that I get unique one "a,b,c"

Comment: @user_123 your solution will select 1st row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works with your data example, and I believe that it will also work with larger datasets.

```
inx <- !duplicated(apply(df1, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "")))
df1[inx, ]
  v1 v2 v3
1  a  b  c
4  x  y  z
```